How we can add timestamp on frames of video recording using Camera 2 Api in the android
I need to add timestamp on frame of video recording. I tried with MediaRecorder but it's not provide any function to add timestamp on frame. If anyone know to add timestamp using MediaCodec and OpenGL. Please share the full code.
